# How does Laplace transform influences integrals?

Tags: laplace-transform

Let $\rho(x,t)$ denote a function of space, $x$ and time, $t$, and let $\hat{\rho}(x,s)$ denote its Laplace transform wrt time.

Assume I need to calculate the Laplace transform of the integral
$$
\int_0^\pi \left( \int_x^1 \rho(\xi,t) d\xi\right) dx .
$$
Is it true that:
$$
\mathcal{L}\left[{\int_0^\pi \left( \int_x^1 \rho(\xi,t) d\xi\right) dx}\right]= \int_0^\pi \left( \int_x^1 \hat{\rho}(\xi,t) d\xi\right) dx
$$
where $\mathcal{L}[f]=\hat{f}$?

Comment: If $\int_0^\infty \int_A |f(y,t)e^{-st} |dy dt < \infty$ then you can change the order of integration. A slightly weaker condition than absolute convergence is uniform convergence. See how it works for $\sum_n \sum_m a_{n,m} = \sum_m \sum_n a_{n,m}$

Comment: So if the integral you mentioned is finite, the answer to my question is positive ? i.e., the Laplace transform of the integral is the integral of Laplace transform?

Comment: [Fubini's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem)